# How to verify the weak convergence?

Tags: measure-theory, real-analysis

Given a finite measure on a compact, take $f_n\in L^1$ with norms $\leq 1$ and suppose that $\int f_n g$ tends to a limit for all continuous $g$. Is it true that then  $\int f_n g$ converge for any $g\in L^\infty$? How can one prove this?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/faq#whatnot Voting to close.

Comment: The answer, by the way, is "no". Could you say a little more about where you came across this problem, which special cases you have already tried, and so forth?

Comment: I need a generalization of this fact for another pair of spaces, where I want to borrow arguments from this standard case. If agruments like the Hahn-Banach theorem work, this could probably help, but I could not restore the proof. 

Comment: Yemon, I agree this is a homework problem (*or if not, it should be*), but (possibly) at graduate level, so I think you're being a little harsh; it is conceivable that a non-(functional analyst) research mathematician, or even a (non-functional) analyst, might find this a bit tricky. There are many interesting special cases of $f_n$ where the answer is "yes"!

Comment: Zen Harper: Can you suggest simple extra assumptions when this is true?

Comment: @Zen: by the time I wrote my 2nd comment, I was starting to reconsider... and on reflection you are right about the level. (By coincidence I was thinking about a very similar question some months ago.)

Comment: Can you recommend some reading for homework, please.

Comment: Well, you really need to be a lot more specific for the problem you have; one nice example is from Fourier Series: take $f_n(x) = e^{inx}$ on the compact interval $[0,2\pi]$ with Lebesgue measure, then the limit is zero for any $g \in L^2$, say (indeed for any $g \in L^1$ by the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma).

I suggest you give a detailed interesting special case which you can't resolve, and then try to see if general theory can be applied. (Actually, most general, abstract theory is originally motivated by interesting special questions - but many textbooks try to hide this!)

Comment: @bib: I don't know of a textbook that would cover this precise question, but it may help to think of the following version: try to find a bounded sequence $(f_n)$ in $L^1[-1,1]$ such that $\int_{-1}^1 f_ng \to 0$ for every continuous $g$ but with $\int_0^1 f_n$ not converging to zero.  

Comment: Interference for a step function supported near zero - ok. Thanks. I'll try to understand what this means for my question.

Comment: In the other direction, asking *what extra assumptions* on $(f_n)$ and the measure will guarantee the answer "yes" seems to me like an interesting question, possibly connected with Tauberian theories. This is exactly the kind of question which can make research interesting, in my opinion, since I doubt there will be any precise necessary/sufficient characterisation from general theory which isn't just tautological.

Comment: Zen Harper, many thanks to you too. I see that the general argument does not work, so I need to estimate what I have.

Comment: The needed "something extra" is a condition that guarantees that the sequence has weakly compact closure in $L^1$, such as no subsequence of $f_n$ is equivalent to the unit vector basis for $\ell^1$.

Comment: Nice... It seems we then have the weak convergence of the arithmetical means, isn't it?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, the above example by Yemon Choi seems to work again.

Answer (score 2):

If $(f_n)$ is a bounded sequence in $L^1(X,\mu)$, it is true that the set of $g\in L^\infty(X,\mu)$ such that $\int_X f_n g\, d\mu$ has a limit in $\mathbb{C}$ is a norm-closed linear subspace of $L^\infty(X,\mu)$. Thus, from a dense set of test functions $g$ you can infer the weak convergence of the sequence $(f_n)$ (to an element of ($L^\infty)^*$, of course, in general not in $L^1$). In conclusion, in general continuous functions are not enough (they are a closed subspace, usually proper, of $L^\infty$), but e.g. simple functions, which are uniformly dense, will do.